# Login page is not permitted in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an application providing several REST endpoints and web pages as well.

```
/products    -- REST endpoint
/cutomers    -- REST endpoint
/ui/catalog  -- Web
/ui/admin    -- Web
```

I want to set up the security so all web starting with `/ui/**` are redirected to a login page and all the others (REST) are challenged with 401 and `WWW-Authenticate`.

With the following settings the login page is not permitted and 401 with the header is sent:

```
@Configuration
@Order(20)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class RestConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();

        httpSecurity.
                requiresChannel().
                requestMatchers(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE).
                requiresSecure();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(10)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class WebUIConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.antMatcher("/ui/**")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Why this doesn't work? I would expect to be redirected to the login page (it works) and the login page to be 200 (it doesn't work).

Comment: And what's your question? It doesn't work or you are looking for advice if you are doing right?

Comment: @Margon sorry, I've put the question explicitly.

Comment: Where is your login page located in the project structure ? Is it inside the /ui ?

Comment: @SB The login page is under `/login` as you can see in the configuration.

Comment: The loginPage configuration should map to a view, so if you have login page under /login, you would need to permit /login antMatcher.

Comment: @SB Why doesn't `.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()` permit the access?

Comment: By configuring loginPage, we are overriding Spring's default login form. 
So, loginPage("/login") tells Spring Security to redirect to "/login". It is the developer's responsibility to provide the login view. Since the login page location is not permitted, it is unable to find the login renderer.

Look at the Spring Security documentation here -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc-authentication.html#form-login-java-configuration
&
Example reference here -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html

Comment: @SB The view is provided, when I remove `RestConfigurationAdapter` everything works fine. Why does not my example work?

Comment: The view is provided but login.html is inside the login directory, right ? And access to login directory is not permitted in the security configuration, thus preventing the page rendering.

Comment: @SB As I said, when the `RestConfigurationAdapter ` is removed, everything is fine. The security config for REST applies for `/login` too, this is the problem. How to solve it?

Comment: I think you can solve it by configuring RestConfigurationAdapter for "/products/**" and "/customers/**". Existing AnyRequestMatcher will match for any supplied request, which includes "/login".

Comment: @Barney SB is right. And  I got your question. See you have two main filters filter1 - ui/** and filter2-rest of the urls. your security has two configurations config1 is order(10) which allows only ui/** but not allows /login. But it can give you /login page when 401/Unauthorized. You can use requestMathcers instead of antMathcher('ui/**'). In request matcher you can allow ui/** and also /login for first configuration.

Comment: Use `http.requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/ui/**", "/login")
        .and() //3
        .authorizeRequests()`.  If my perception is not wrong. it my help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the `WebUIConfigurationAdapter` as follows solves the problem:

```
httpSecurity.requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/ui/**", "/login", "/logout")
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().permitAll();
```

The URL `/login` is set by `WebUIConfigurationAdapter` so it is then excluded by `RestConfigurationAdapter`.

Thanks @PraveenKumarLalasangi for his comment.